# Create new stateful widget inside stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I want to create a stateful MainPage widget that displays stateful CustomTimer timer widget. Time for CustomerTimer I get from the SharedPreferences and set it to **_timerDuration**. So **_timerDuration** can be changed.
The issue is that updates for **_timerDuration** don't affect MainPage and CustomerTimer. I always see initial **_timerDuration** value(10).
But in the same time I see correct(new) _timerDuration in print statements for **build()** and **buildTimerWidget()** functions.

```
  class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _timerDuration = 10;

  Future<void> loadTimerDuration() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _timerDuration = prefs.getInt("timer_duration")!;
      print("Get time duration:${_timerDuration}");
      _controller.start();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadTimerDuration();
  }

  Widget buildTimerWidget() {
    print("build timer with duration: ${_timerDuration}");
    return CustomTimer(
        controller: _controller,
        begin: Duration(seconds: _timerDuration), //begin is a final variable
        end: const Duration(),
        builder: (time) {
          return Text("${time.minutes}:${time.seconds}",
              style: kLabelTextStyle);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("build main page with duration: ${_timerDuration}");
    Widget timerWidget = buildTimerWidget();//I want to create a new CustomTimer widget on any update of _timerDuration variable.
    return Scaffold(
      body: timerWidget
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am assuming that's not the right place to call _controller.start(), i can try it out if you can share the complete code

Comment: @SankethB.K controller is only responsible for start/stop/reset actions. But it cannot change timer duration. 
Full MainPage widget: https://codeshare.io/BAlbdn

Comment: Try this `https://pastebin.com/RQF8UvAp`, apparently the problem is CustomTimer will not take the _timerDuration when you call controller.start, but it takes the _timerDuration when it is mounted. So you can display that widget only after you load the _timerDuration from shared preferences. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.